# Sql query to select all the sub items in the same table

Tags: sql

I have a table in which one column depends another column. The table I have some what resembles the below

```
FolderId | ParentFolderID | Name
1        |  null          | ParentFolder 
2        |  1             | Test1
3        |  2             | Test2
4        |  3             | Test3
5        |  null          | Test4
6        |  null          | Test5
7        |  6             | Test6
8        |  5             | Test7
```

I need to filter out the Parent Folder Id's which points out the root folderID 1. And the output should be like the below table:

```
FolderId | ParentFolderID |Name
1        |  null          |ParentFolder
2        |  1             |Test1
3        |  2             |Test2
4        |  3             |Test3
```

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Which SQL platform you are using?

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE ParentFolderID IS NULL
AND FolderID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT A.*
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN CTE1 C
ON A.ParentFolderID = C.FolderID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE1;
```

[dbfiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=08a9ca6f38c550cba8c44d699b5b5329)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from @TableName S 
where S.FolderId in (select ParentFolderId from @TableName) or S.ParentFolderId is not null
```

Comment: This is working, But I need to get results only for the parent folder ID that is starting from the value ID 1. This query returns all the Folders that have parentFolderId which depends on other Id's as well

Comment: If table is small or select is not big (<100 or <1000 rows) better to select all this 100 rows and then programatically using recursive function to filter that out.

In sql you can make messy x joins, where x is max amount of nesting.